# Google Tag Manger: Parse error. ',' expected

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I would like to save this Facebook pixel code in Google Tag Manager. However, the `JavaScript` compiler returns this error each time:

> Error at line 14, character 71: Parse error. ',' expected.

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out but I could not. I would GREATLY appreciate any and all help to resolve this issue. Thank you!

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '579694185890697');
fbq('set','agent','tmgoogletagmanager', '579694185890697');
fbq('track', "PageView");
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', { 
      content_type: 'vehicle', // REQUIRED: DO NOT change this, must be set to 'vehicle'
      content_ids: [$("[itemprop=vehicleIdentificationNumber]").text();],
      make: $("[itemprop=manufacturer]").text();, // RECOMMENDED 
      model: $("[itemprop=model]").text();, // RECOMMENDED 
      year: $("[itemprop=vehicleModelDate]").text();, // RECOMMENDED 
      state_of_vehicle: $("[itemprop=itemCondition]").text();, // RECOMMENDED 
      exterior_color: $("[itemprop=vehicleIdentificationNumbercolor]") 
      transmission:  $("[itemprop=vehicleTransmission]").text();, 
      price: $("[itemprop=price]").text();, // RECOMMENDED, up to 2 decimals optional 
      currency: 'USD' // REQUIRED: if price and preferred_price_range is used 
});  
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=579694185890697&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: You are putting semicolons `;` in the wrong places, eg `.text();,` should be `.text(),` or just `.text()` in the case of the array item

Comment: Thank you, Patrick! It's resolved!